# SSH behind a NAT enabled router errors

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh

I have a Netgear router and I installed OpenSSH. When I try:

```
ssh deadman@192.168.0.4
```

My ssh works fine and I am able to enter to the ssh terminal, but when I try it with a remote terminal like:

```
ssh deadman@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I dont see anything. If I try:

```
deadman -W deadman@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I get:

```
Bad stdio forwarding specification 'deadman@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'
```

(note that XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is my routers ip)

[image]

In my router settings I have enabled port forwarding

[image]

Comment: Now that you have published your (not professional equipment) router's public IP, expect some DOSsing.

Comment: It is not static ip so i guess as soon as i restart router ip will change

Comment: Last login: Sun May 25 14:14:33 2014 from 192.168.0.4
deadman@<Unknown>:~$

Comment: I only had to attempt _two_ different passwords...

Comment: How did you do it I wasn't able to login it kept waiting forever

Comment: Were you trying from **inside** your network?  And dawud, you *might* want to be a bit more circumspect about posting admissions of possibly-unlawful activity on a public forum.  What you post is up to you, of course; I'm just thinking out loud here.

Comment: You published your IP, and a username. I issued `ssh deadman@$ip` and guessed you password. Disable password login and enable pubkey authentication. Use some sort of DOS mitigation like fail2ban or don't expose your router to the Internet like this.

Comment: @MadHatter He was, but he also has an internal IP.

Comment: Yes, and i tried connect bot from my android too, but failed. I changed my IP and systems password @dawud is my system still at risk?

Comment: If you read the linked duplicate question, you'll see it deals with the issue of connecting to one internal system from another internal system using the publicly-forwarded IP address at the gateway.  At the moment, that is my understanding of what you're trying to do; is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but i tried to connect from the connectBot android which is connected to a different network too, still there it gets the timeoout thing

Comment: Then I think you have two different questions.  One is about connecting from inside your home network, and that is dealt with by the duplicate.  The other is about connecting via connectbot, and that isn't a duplicate, but it's also not discussed at all in this question (only briefly mentioned in the comments).  I would suggest that you overhaul your question so it deals much more clearly with the connectbot issue - though if this is a home setup, it may still be off-topic for SF.

Comment: @dawud Mentioning the IP isn't a problem. Somebody would find it anyway, scanning all 3.7 billion "public" IPv4 addresses for SSH servers has been done before. If an SSH server is not secure enough to post its IPv4 address without worrying, then that's the first problem to fix. Reading the IP address on a forum and trying to connect to it, is probably OK. Trying to guess usernames and passwords is not OK. Configuring the server to only accept public keys as authentication is good advice.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am sorry for my mistake i did not know a lot about this before, the possible duplicate link you gave MadHatter i did understand the scenario, and trying to browse other forums for similar questions. Thanks for your help though